# Angular 8 with Ivy how to verify it is used

Tags: angular

Today I installed Angular 8 final version.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Generated a simple app with:

```
ng new sampleApp
```

On https://angular.io/guide/ivy site I found that I have to modify `tsconfig.app.json` file to enable Ivy. Like this:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
}
```

My question is after I perform build how can I verify that Ivy is in place and used as a rendering engine?

Comment: What I’d do is build one with Ivy and one without and compare size. There is  a better way for sure but this one will do the trick :)

Comment: Not sure if there's a way, only way is to check the ng build output on your terminal for main.ts file size

Comment: @Dino yes, that works for sure :-)

Comment: @penleychan main.ts? The typescript file?

Comment: You know, after ng build you get output of files names on your terminal one of em is `main.[chunk]... 25 kB` etc

Comment: @robert easiest way come to my mind is check on the size of both builds, and verify that is there a significant difference in the size of the build or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

New rendering engine prefers adding expando properties to many objects rather than new wrapping type.

You can open your application in chrome browser and check if any of elements inside your Angular application has `__ngContext__` property.

[image]

https://ivy.ng-run.com/

Comment: This approach also works with Angular 9.0.0-rc.1. Just tested.

Comment: Running cli 8.3.24 to ng new project --enable-ivy. This doesn't seem to be true any more. "Cannot read property '__ngContext__' of undefined"

Comment: @Hao That is still true

Comment: @yurzui You are right. Tested again. It works on certain element. But not on every element.

Comment: To be clear, if you see `__ngContext__` that means you **are** using Ivy.

Answer (score 7):

When you set `enableIvy` to `true`

```
...
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
...
```

then `ngcc` command is executed by running `ng serve` or `ng build`. You can recognize it in the console easily because it will start printing out something like this

```
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015

...
```

The seconds possible way is by checking bundle size as it was mentioned in comments.

Also there is a short paragraph about Ivy and Bazel on [Angular blog](https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27) that we will get more info about Ivy next week.

> We know there’s lots of excitement for our forthcoming opt-in
>   previews. We’ll be providing individual updates on these next week on
>   this blog, so stay tuned!

Comment: Yes, just checked with Ivy turned on I get these Compiling @angular/core lines in the console. Thank you.